# E-Commerce website product with price

Tags: user-behavior, e-commerce, web

Why does many **e-commerce or B2B websites** like http://www.alibaba.com/ http://flipkart.com/  displays product with price. Is it not possible to make user to click on the product without displaying its **price**. Is there any other thing we could add instead of price?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not show the price? We need more background information.

Comment: Many users will not go through the product because of the price. What I am expecting is the user should click or goaway not only because of price tag.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that *not* showing the price is a better user experience? I see no reason why you'd suggest not displaying a price unless you have some reasoning behind suggesting it.

Comment: JonW. I am asking for the situation on which the price is high. If the user feel the price of product is too high, then how could they further proceed on that product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could communicate the price on the detail page of the product without showing it in the overview. This would achieve what you are asking for.

However, i think you should rethink this problem. If users go away because they think the price is to high, try to change their expectations. Apple, for example, has fairly high priced products. Yet they do communicate this in an overview page. The reason this works for apple, is because users expect products to be pricey. You can manage expectation by graphic design and copy writing.